# cpprestsdk cookie handling

Tags: c++, cookies, casablanca

I'm using the cpprestsdk in a native Windows desktop client app (written in WTL), so it uses WinHttp.  Now, WinHttp has automatic cookie handling, but in the cpprestsdk when I get a response that has Set-Cookie headers, the cookies don't get set on the WinHttp session, and I have to manually add a Cookie header to each subsequent request (mostly we're talking about auth cookies).

I don't see anywhere in the source of the cpprestsdk that it's specifically disabling WinHttp's automatic cookie handling, so kind of flummoxed and wondering if anyone can help.